# sql server table values differ by space

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am running queries that total values and group based on value of another column, in this case that column being ITEM.

In the results I find that ITEM is sometimes returned twice for certain values thus causing the totals to be incorrect. Looking at the individual values I found the values to be:
 `'20'` and `'  20'`. Now I tried updating the table and removing all leading and trailing spaces but it does not seem to have helped. Any ideas>

```
update TableA
set item = ltrim(rtrim(item))
```

and the totals results show

```
   item    count
   20      2000
     3     1000
     20    500
   3       2000
   34      5999
```

how can i change this.

Comment: @vbNewbie: Is that the complete UPDATE statement you issued? You might not hit the rows you need to hit if there is some WHERE (or GROUP BY) clause

Comment: They might be carriage returns or tabs rather than spaces. If so this function might help http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/10/sql-server-2008-enhenced-trim-function-remove-trailing-spaces-leading-spaces-white-space-tabs-carriage-returns-line-feeds/

Comment: how would I use a where in the statement @skarmats

Comment: @vbNewbie: Just by adding `WHERE someCondition`. You can even JOIN in UPDATE statements. But I take it, you did neither of these. Or is there more to the UPDATE statement?

Comment: I know how to use where but If say where item = ????

Comment: how to apply function to table column - @martin

Comment: @vbNewbie: I'm not saying you should. I was just asking, if you did ;-) I'd go follow Martin's suggestion above. If you are executing the UPDATE on the correct table and database and nothing changes, then it's not a space but a line break or similar and LTRIM/RTRIM won't take care of those. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: fix your application or you'll get more bad values.  can you just make the column an int?

Comment: fixed, thanks Martin for the script

Comment: I would question the wisdom of storing ints as strings?

Comment: item column contains sample data and not actual data which contains alpha characters attached to the numeric value...

Answer (score 1):

You could run something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LTrimX(@str VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @trimchars VARCHAR(10)
    SET @trimchars = CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(32)

    IF @str LIKE '[' + @trimchars + ']%'
        SET @str = SUBSTRING(@str, PATINDEX('%[^' + @trimchars + ']%', @str), 8000)
    RETURN @str
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RTrimX(@str VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @trimchars VARCHAR(10)
    SET @trimchars = CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(32)
    IF @str LIKE '%[' + @trimchars + ']'
        SET @str = REVERSE(dbo.LTrimX(REVERSE(@str)))
    RETURN @str
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TrimX(@str VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    RETURN dbo.LTrimX(dbo.RTrimX(@str))
END
GO


/* Perform Update */
UPDATE TableA SET item = dbo.TrimX(item)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

if all of your "item" values are integers, with no leading zeros, you can do this:

```
update TableA set item = convert(int,item)
```

or even something like this:

```
update TableA set item=convert(int,item) WHERE item like '%20' or item like '%3'
```

Answer (score 0):

First try finding the ascii value for the items

```
SELECT ITEM, ASCII(ITEM)
FROM TABLEA
```

Then do the update with the where clause

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET item = ltrim(rtrim(item))
WHERE ascii(item) = --Put the ascii value of the item that you want to update like 32 or 50 or 49 etc
```

If you have many item then you can use a cursor to loop through.
Hope this helps.